# How to install libavcodec with Apt for Cygwin?

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having some trouble with installing new packages using cygwin's `apt` version of `apt-get`. The issue is, when I run the commands below, I receive

```
Coder@Coder-WIN10 ~
$ apt-cyg update
--2018-08-21 14:53:56--  http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com//x86_64/setup.bz2
Resolving cygwin.mirror.constant.com (cygwin.mirror.constant.com)... 108.61.5.83

Connecting to cygwin.mirror.constant.com (cygwin.mirror.constant.com)|108.61.5.83|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3725925 (3.6M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘setup.bz2’

setup.bz2           100%[===================>]   3.55M  4.63MB/s    in 0.8s    
2018-08-21 14:53:58 (4.63 MB/s) - ‘setup.bz2’ saved [3725925/3725925]  

Updated setup.ini    
Coder@Coder-WIN10 ~
$ apt-cyg install libavcodec-extra-56
Installing libavcodec-extra-56
Unable to locate package libavcodec-extra-56
```

I've tried multiple packages, but not all are installing without issue. What is the approach that I should take when installing packages that may not be available with the current mirror?

Comment: VTC as not reproducible because the author of this question hasn't signed on to Ask Ubuntu for one year.